# Connecting multiple Components to the React Redux Store

Tags: reactjs, redux

I just recently started working with Redux and I managed to connect my `<App />` component to the store with this code:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    ...state,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    writeSomething: () => dispatch(writeSomething),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

It's pretty simple, when I press a button, writeSomething gets called and it turns a false into a true, and it works just fine.

But then I wanted to connect my other components to the store and noticed that I have to copy paste the entire code from up there, and then I also have to import writeSomething. This looks very repetitive and not fun, so there must be a better way to do this, right? I searched around and couldn't really find what I was looking for, so I'm wondering: is there an actually easier and faster way to connect to the store or do I have to copy/paste my code for each component that I want to connect to the redux store?

Comment: use HOC higher oreder component !

Comment: Why not try hooks. react-redux has hooks called useDispatch, useSelector. useDispatch will dispatch and action while useSelector will be to get state. Doing hooks way is fun.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i guess thats the structure we have to follow but u can use context for prevent that or you can use HOC for avoid the duplicating

Answer (score 0):

you can use HOC to avoid repetition in code,or you can also use custom hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try hooks. react-redux has hooks called useDispatch, useSelector. useDispatch will dispatch and action while useSelector will be to get state. Doing hooks way is fun.

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/react-redux-hooks-useselector-and-usedispatch-f7d8c7f75cdd

With this you'll obtain cleaner and more organized code.

Comment: Never used hooks, idk if learning 2 things at once is a good idea but I will give a try